# does MyBatis work inside Freemarker?

Tags: java, mybatis, freemarker

I configured MyBatis to work with Freemarker like so:

```
    <setting name="defaultScriptingLanguage" value="FreeMarker"/>
</settings>
<typeAliases>
    <typeAlias type="org.mybatis.scripting.freemarker.FreeMarkerLanguageDriver" alias="FreeMarker"/>
</typeAliases>
```

Then I have a select in MyBatis that I need to convert to Freemarker:

```
<select id="find" parameterType="map" resultType="com.example.MyType">
    SELECT
        <if test="_databaseId == 'sqlserver'">
            TOP (${r"#{rowLimit}"})
        </if>
    FROM myexampletable
    <choose>
        <when test="_databaseId == 'oracle'">
            WHERE rownum &lt;= ${r"#{rowLimit}"}
        </when>
        <when test="_databaseId == 'postgresql' || _databaseId == 'h2'">
            LIMIT ${r"#{rowLimit}"}
        </when>
    </choose>
</select>
```

(The above code simplified for the sake of brevity.)

The problem is this does not work at all, the MyBatis tags are ignored completely and all the TOP and LIMIT keywords appear in the same SQL command, no matter what DB dialect I use.

I have to say it had worked perfectly fine, before I added Freemarker scripting. Is this a bug or a feature? Can I make both languages work in one script at the same time?

Comment: it *looks* like you might need to use some third party plugins [Freemarker scripting](https://github.com/mybatis/freemarker-scripting) and [Freemarker plugin for mybatis](http://blog.mybatis.org/2015/03/freemarker-plugin-for-mybatis.html) Note: it was just a quick search.  I can add it as an answer if it truns out to be the only way.

Comment: Yes, I already am using MyBatis-Freemarker plugin as described at: http://www.mybatis.org/freemarker-scripting/ The Freemarker part works fine, the problem with this, that MyBatis stops working inside the Freemarker script. Yes, I should have said that in the main question.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of suggesting is going to the github repo or the mybatis.org website and seeing if you can put in an github issue - or contact one of the contributors.  If you get it figured out with their help let me know through a comment and answer your question for some reputation!  Sorry I couldnt help out more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I created a github issue to solve this riddle and the answer was helpful but negative:

> No, you cannot use both XML and Freemaker syntax in the same statement.

You can read our full comments in the following issue:

https://github.com/mybatis/freemarker-scripting/issues/33